# Sequences of Riemann Integrable Functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that ${f_n}$ is a sequence of Riemann integrable functions on $[0,1]$ that converges uniformly to $0$. Show that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}||f_n||_{L^1}=0.$$
Where do I even begin with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You have to show that for any $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N$ so that for all $n\ge N$ you have
$
\Vert f_n\Vert_{L^1}<\epsilon.
$

Towards this end, you can use the following facts:

1. Since $(f_n)$ converges to $0$ uniformly on $[0,1]$, for any
   $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N$ such that $|f_n(x)|<\epsilon$ for all
   $n\ge N$ and all $x\in [0,1]$.
2. If $-M\le f(x)\le M$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and if $f$ is Riemann integrable over $[0,1]$, then
   $$
   -M\le \int_0^1 |f(x)|\,dx\le M.
   $$